# Rendring the component, how much object the state variable have (in React.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't know, whether it is correct or wrong while rendering, the component renders the number of objects it has plus one extra time (6 objects + 1), 7 times the component renders, Please suggest to me is it correct or wrong with reason. If I type 5 letters in the 5th task, it renders 30 times, which means in the 5th index, it have 5 objects so 25+(1 extra time in each object *5)=30 times I think it's a huge performance issue.

Create-task.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
    import store from "../redux/store";
    import actions from "../redux/actions";
    import '../styles/create-task.scss';
    import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
    import TaskTemplate from "./task-template";
    import SaveTemplate from "./save-template";
    const CreateTask=()=> {
        // const [templates, setTemplates]=useState([]);
        const onTaskCreate = () => {
            store.dispatch({type: actions.ON_CREATE_TASK, payload: {'taskCount':taskCount + 1,'save':false}})
            addTemplate();
            store.dispatch({type:actions.ON_ADD_TEMPLATES, payload:template});
        }
        const createTask = useSelector(({reducers}) => {
            const {taskCount, taskDetails,save,templates} = reducers;
            return {taskCount, taskDetails,save, templates};
        });
        const {taskCount, taskDetails,save,templates} = createTask;
        const {userData}=taskDetails;
        const globalTemplates=createTask.templates;
        let template = globalTemplates;
        const addTemplate = () => {
                template.push(<div key={`template${taskCount}`} id={`task${taskCount+1}`}><TaskTemplate/></div>);
            return template;
        }
        useEffect(()=>{
            // setTemplates(globalTemplates)
        },[])
    
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={"create-task"}>
                    <div>TASKS <span className={"task-count"}> {taskCount} </span></div>
                    <div className={"add-task-button"} onClick={onTaskCreate}>
                        <button>+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {templates && templates.map((template)=>template)}
                {/*{save?<SaveTemplate/>:templates.map((template)=> template)}*/}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default CreateTask;
```

Task.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
    import store from "../redux/store";
    import actions from "../redux/actions";
    import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';
    import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
    import TimePicker from 'react-bootstrap-time-picker';
    import {wrapMapToPropsConstant} from "react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps";
    const TaskTemplate=(props)=>{
        const [dateValue, dateChange] = useState(new Date());
        const [time, timeChange] = useState('10:00');
       
        const tasks = useSelector(({reducers}) => {
            const { taskDetails,edit, createTask} = reducers;
            return {taskDetails, edit, createTask};
        });
        const{edit,taskDetails,createTask}=tasks;
       
        const onFieldChange=(e)=>{
            let editingTaskId=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
            editingTaskId=editingTaskId.split("task")[1]-1;
            createTask.map((data,index)=>{
                if(index === editingTaskId){
                    createTask[editingTaskId]["userData"][e.target.name]=e.target.value;
                }
            })
        }
        const dateChangeFormat = (val) =>{
            var splitDate=val.toLocaleString('hu-HU').substr(0,12);
            splitDate=splitDate.replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll(".","-");
            return splitDate;
        }
        
        return(
            <>
                    <div>
                        <label>Task Description</label>
                        <input name={"task_msg"}  defaultValue={ props.task && props.task.task_msg && props.task.task_msg } onChange={(e)=>{onFieldChange(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <DatePicker
                    onChange={onDateChange}
                    value={props.task?props.task.original_date:dateValue}
                    format={"y-MM-dd"}
                    name={"task_date"}
                    clearIcon={""}
                    />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label>Time</label>
                    <TimePicker start="10:00" end="21:00"  step={30} onChange={onTimeChange} value={props.task?props.task.task_time:time} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label>Assign User</label>
                    <input name={"assigned_user"} defaultValue={ props.task && props.task.task_msg && props.task.assigned_user} onChange={(e)=>{onFieldChange(e)}}/>
                    </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>onFormSave(e)}> Save </button>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default TaskTemplate;
```

Reducer. js

```
import actions from "./actions";
const stateInit={
    taskCount:0,
    taskDetails:[],
    templates:[],
    createTask:[],
    userData: {
            task_msg: '',
            task_date: '',
            task_time: 36000,
            assigned_user: '',
            time_zone: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
            is_completed: 0,
        }

};
export default function tasks(state=stateInit, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case actions.ON_CREATE_TASK:{
            const {taskCount,save}=action.payload;
            return {
                ...state,
                taskCount: taskCount,
                save:save,
                createTask: [...state.createTask,{userData:{...state.userData}}],
            }
        }
        case actions.ON_VALUE_CHANGE:{
            return {
                ...state,
                createTask: action.payload,
            }
        }

        case actions.ON_ADD_TEMPLATES:{
            return{
                ...state,
                templates: action.payload,
            }
        }
       
        default:{
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Avoid reading objects from your useSelector . For example const { userData } = useSelector(....) . Instead you should be doing const message = useSelector(state => state?.reducer?.userData?.message) . Here the component wont re-render unless the value in the message changes . But the component subscribed to userData will re-render even if one of the keys in it changes because we get new `userData` for each store update .

Comment: @Shyam       const tasks = useSelector((state) => {
        const taskDetails=state?.reducers?.taskDetails;
        const  edit  = state?.reducers?.edit;
        const  createTask  = state?.reducers?.createTask;
        return {taskDetails, edit, createTask};
    });

As per your advice, I changed it like this, but I can't see any difference while rendering

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you do not control when the framework decides to re render objects that are bound to elements in the dom tree. It sort of detects that for you.

The long answer is to understand the lifecycle-and-state of objects as well as two-way bindings and what triggers render-updates:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
- https://react-cn.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html